# Can't mount network drive - Permission denied

Tags: mount, raspbian, cifs

I'm running raspbian on an RPi2B and I'm trying to mount a network drive. I've tried the following:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=admin,password=passwd //192.168.1.1/root /mnt/myshare`

But I keep getting permission denied error.

I can access this share fine on my macbook pro with the same credentials so I don't understand what's going on.

I have dashes (-) in my password so I tried enclosing it in quotes, escaping the dashes etc. but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you already tried to use a credential file? Just in case it is a syntax issue?

Comment: Yes I've tried that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a painful day or so of trying to figure this out, it turns out I needed to set sec=ntlm and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo su -
mount -t smbfs -o username=admin,password=passwd //192.168.1.1/root /mnt/myshare
                                                              ^^^^
```

Are you sure to set every permission to root ?

Comment: That gives me this: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'. I'm not sure what you mean by 'Are you sure to set every permission to root', can you explain please?

Comment: I've removed the password from the share and tried with `-o guest` but still get permission denied

Comment: When you want to login to root you have to `username=root` not `username=admin`

Comment: Yes when I ssh'd in I used the root account but the share username was admin although I have removed the password protection and I'm still getting permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You basically try to ssh (cifs is an operation comparable to ssh) into the 'root' directory where you need to have the correct permissions for user 'admin'. If 'root' has not at least read permissions set for user 'admin' then user 'admin' cannot ssh into directory 'root' even if the credentials given in the ssh command are correct.

Comment: I've tried ssh with root but still getting permission denied

Comment: I also removed password and tried with -o guest but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/sharedfolername /mountlocation --verbose -o credentials=/credentials/file/location
```

But creating a file at the credentials file location with the contents:

username=yourusername
password=yourpassword